# Adding computer's description to BGInfo

Tags: windows, script, desktop

Is it possible to add the `computer description` value to BGInfo?

The closest information I've found so far is the `<Host Name>` (available in the defaults field) but I guess I would have to write a custom User defined field in order to get the description.

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: Is it possible to add the computer description value to BGInfo? If so, how?

Answer (score -2):

If you create a custom field as a WMI Query,
Select 'WMI_OperatingSystem' as the WMI Class
Class Property  is ' Description

The WMI Query should then be 'SELECT Description FROM Win32_OperatingSystem'